# Trying to add a custom image to Opensearch but cannot find "ui/assets" folder?

Tags: kibana, dashboard, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am trying to add a custom image to OpenSearch dashboards. I want to use locally hosted images and save them in the assets folder.

According to Opensearch: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/dashboards/branding/

> if you really want to use locally hosted images, save your images inside assets, and then configure opensearch_dashboards.yml to use the correct paths. You can access locally stored images through the **ui/assets** folder.

Where can I find this path `ui/assets` ?

I am using a docker container to run `opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:latest`. I tried searching in the container through the interactive shell for this path:`ui/assets` but I could not find it.

What I also tried but did not work:

I found a folder called `assets` along this path:

`/usr/share/opensearch-dashboards/assets/` and placed my logo.png in there but it did not work.

I tried creating a `ui/assets/` in opensearch-dashboards folder and placed my logo.png in there but no luck.
Like this: `/usr/share/opensearch-dashboards/ui/assets/logo.png`

Answer (score 0):

I am running OpenSearch Dashboards 2.4.1 in a Docker container, and here's what I did:

1. Created a folder on my host machine with my logo, e.g. ./assets
2. Updated my docker-compose.yml file to mount the assets folder in the container:

volumes:
- ./assets:/usr/share/opensearch-dashboards/assets

3. The logo will be served up at this URL: http://localhost:5601/ui/assets/logo.svg